# python joomraa.py: error: too few arguments in pen test open source

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

> ```
> usage: joomraa.py [-h] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [-e EMAIL] [-s SEARCH]
>                   [-x EXPLOIT]
>                   url
> ```
>
> joomraa.py: error: too few arguments
>   [Finished in 0.5s with exit code 2]

How do I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: What did you do that it thrown you error? What was the error? You didn't tell us ANYTHING about what your problem is. Also, don't use external pages for sharing screenshots - either put them directly into your question or don't even use them and just copy-paste the text.

Comment: https://github.com/XiphosResearch/exploits/blob/master/Joomraa/joomraa.py code

Answer (score 0):

According to the joomraa.py documentation you need to "Choose the username, password and e-mail address to use and point it at the URL for your Joomla website." The other arguments are optional.

It looks like you don't have the required minimum arguments.

Your input should look something like:

```
joomraa.py -u hacker -p password -e hacker@example.com http://localhost:8080/joomla
```

Read the documentation here:
https://github.com/XiphosResearch/exploits/blob/master/Joomraa/README.md